# ¿Cómo detectar patrones de patentes argentinas?

Tags: python

Como puedo generar un sistema de patentes argentinas ya sean viejas o nuevas en Python usando tuplas (creería que así es mas fácil y rápido para que no sea tan problemático y legible el código). Estoy aprendiendo este lenguaje y me cuesta aun.

Lo he visto en un ejercicio de internet y no tiene resultado, pensé en algo como poner el abecedario en una variable de patente y mediante un input que el usuario escriba su propia patente y verificar que sea de acuerdo a las de Argentinas ( 3 letras y 3 números o la actual que es 2 letras 3 números 2 letras) y aunque escriba cualquier cosa solo le pida ese sistema asi. 
Mi código quedaría así , me faltaría recorrer con un for si esta bien hecho pero no se como hacerlo

```
patente = str(input("Ingrese su patente en forma LLL NNN o LL NNN LL: "))

while True:
    patente.lower()
    if patente[0:3] != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyz" and patente[4:7] == "123456789":
        patente = str(input("Escribió mal las letras de su patente, intente otra vez: "))
    elif patente [4:7] != "123456789" and patente[0:3] == "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyz":
        patente = str(input("Escribió mal los numeros de su patente, intente otra vez: "))
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask]. Aparte de tu duda, es recomendable que agregues el código de lo que hayas implementado, y especifiques dónde tienes problemas para poder ayudarte. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para agregar lo necesario. Saludos

Comment: Gracias espero haber formulado bien la pregunta ahora con el codigo puesto.

Comment: Oye Lucas, te he dado un +1 por que tu pregunta me pareció muy útil y bien formulada, invito al resto de la comunidad a hacer lo mismo. Sigue así!

Answer (score 4):

Podes usar expresiones regulares para resolver eso (es una de las tantas formas).
Documentación de expresiones regulares [expresiones regulares](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

El codigo para resolver el problema seria

```
import re
patronPatenteVieja=re.compile("[a-z]{3}[\d]{3}") "expresion regular de 3 letras seguidas de dos números"
patronPatenteNueva=re.compile("[a-z]{2}[\d]{2}[a-z]{2}") 
pat = raw_input("Ingrese su patente en forma LLLNNN o LLNNNLL: ")

if patronPatenteVieja.search(pat) or patronPatenteNueva.search(pat):

    print("Es una patente")
else:
    print("no es")
```

o mejor aun una manera no tan complicada

```
pat = raw_input("Ingrese su patente en forma LLLNNN o LLNNNLL: ")

if(pat[0:3].isalpha() and pat[4:6].isdigit()):
    print("Es una patente vieja")

if(pat[0:2].isalpha() and pat[3:4].isdigit()) and pat[5:6].isalpha():
    print("Es una patente nueva")
```

Comment: Que buena respuesta Mauri! te he dado un +1, invito a todos a hacer lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

La patente nueva es

```
[a-z]{2}[\d]{3}[a-z]{2}
```

ya que son 2 letras, 3 números y 2 letras.